# android: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.Process finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android

when I compile mapbox my project will have a error.

```
compile ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:0.7.4@aar'){
    transitive=true
}
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I tried to use `multiDexEnabled true`, but it doesn't work.
And I tried to find the same .jar files, I think it is `'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'`,I delete it and no work.
I don't know how to solve it, please help.